# In graph $G$, for each vertex v with even and positive degree, There is a non-trivial cycle $(\ge 3)$ from $v$ to $v$.

Tags: graph-theory

Having troubles with the following problem, thinking about induction, but can't go further:

In graph $G$, for each vertex $v$ with even and positive degree, There is a non-trivial cycle  $(\ge 3)$ from $v$ to $v$.

Comment: If a graph having positive and even degree, then we have pair of (in, out). 
This is definition of Euler graph.

Comment: But what about the 3-path? The middle element has degree 2, but there is certainly no cycle.

Comment: It says "for each vertex" so if I understand it correctly, *every* vertex in $G$ has positive and even degree.

Comment: I understand it that we have such a non-trivial cycle for each vertex with even and positive degree, but no actual assumptions on the graph. That is what the formulation incline, though the problem seems more reasonable with your interpretation Arsen.

Comment: @OveAhlman I interpret it this way because otherwise you are definitely right, there are many counter examples.

Comment: The claim is false if $G$ is a tree and contains at least one even degree vertex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually with these information, statement doesn't imply *Euler circuit* exists. Notice that we are not given $G$ is **connected** or **finite**. But still, since $G$ is not a multigraph by convention, smallest component of $G$ (may be connected or disconnected) satisfying the condition given is $K_3$, which has a cycle of length at least $3$ for all of its vertices. For the rest, you can use the argument "for every vertex in $G$, number of enters to that vertex is equal to number of exists from that vertex". If $G$ is a finite graph, you can eventually find a cycle of length greater than or equal to $3$ for every vertex. If $G$ is not finite, I'm not sure infinite cycles are included to cycles of length more than $3$ or not.